# How to convert single-byte charset (non-ASCII) ByteArray into Kotlin UTF8 String (How to avoid ��?)

Tags: string, kotlin, utf-8, character-encoding, non-unicode

I have API that produces results in specific single-byte charset (WIN 1257) and I am reading this result in Kotlin as:

```
val connection = URL("http://192.168.1.21:92/someAPI").openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
var byteArray: ByteArray = ByteArray(10000000)
connection.inputStream.read(byteArray)
val tmp = String(byteArray, Charsets.UTF_8).trim()
```

Of course, this is clearly incorrect code, because it presumes that byteArray is the representation of the string that is encoded in UTF-8. It may be desirable to correct this code by using `Charsets.WIN_1257`, but there is no such option in Kotlin. **My byte array is the representation of the string that is WIN-1257 encoded - how can I get UTF-8 string?**

Here is simple test code that isolates my problem and that can be run in https://play.kotlinlang.org:

```
/**
 * You can edit, run, and share this code.
 * play.kotlinlang.org
 */
fun main() {
    var byteArray: ByteArray = listOf(0xe2, 0x72).map { it.toByte() }.toByteArray()
    println(String(byteArray, Charsets.UTF_8))
}
```

On can se that UTF_8 produces the result:

```
�r
```

But I expect:

```
ār
```

Comment: Change to `Charsets.ISO_8859_1` and the output changes to `âr`. Ok, doesn't look exactly like your expected result but avoids `�` ;-) Do you have more examples of characters that turn into `�`?

Comment: It depends on the tools. Postman automatically applies charset which outputs âr, but Kotlin applies charset which outputs � for any non-ASCII character. This is really strange, that Android Charsets structure is so poor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into [`Charset.availableCharsets`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#availableCharsets--); just `Charset.forName("Windows-1257")` might work.

Comment: Indeed, String(byteArray, Charset.forName("windows-1257")) solved my problem. NB this works in Android Studio and its emulators, but https://play.kotlinlang.org gives "Unresolved reference: Charset". Of course, I am concerted what happens on device and not in online playground.

Comment: `Charset` is pure java, and `Charsets.UTF_8` also is a `Charset`. So weird.